# Using libusb in open frameworks on OS X

Tags: xcode, openframeworks

I wanted to try some things with openFrameworks but got stuck trying to use libusb, which is not available as of addon.

I copied it in the "other" folder but don't no how to include it in the project.

Answer (score 1):

The included ofxKinect addon includes compiled libusb and headers. If you add that add-on via the project generator, you'll have access to libusb.

Comment: thanks. that worked! I'd still be interested how to get this to work properly as it seems important to know for using other libraries

Comment: You're trying to figure out how the data should be structured in your xcode project?

Comment: yes. how would I go about this if there wasn't ofxKinect. I did try to add .dylib files to the project but libusb.h was never available until I included ofxKinect